# Regular expression to match an arbitrary length of characters in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, email-validation

I m just learning regular expression matching using javascript, and have a doubt regarding the scenario described below.

I'm trying to validate email, with condition below:

> Format should be `xxx@yyy.zzz` where
>   A) "xxx", "yyy" and "zzz" parts
>   can take values only between lowercase a and z
>   B) The length of zzz,
>   yyy and xxx parts are arbitrary (should be minimum one though)

Now I understand I can build the regex like this:
**EDIT:
CORRECTED REG EXP
    `/[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/`**

and the above would evaluate a string like "aaa@aaa.aaa" as true.

But my concern is, in the above expression if i provide `"a999@aaa.aaa"`, again it would evaluate as true. Now, if i modify the reg ex as `**/[a-z]{1,}@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/**` even then it would evaluate `"a999@aaa.aaa"` as true because of the presence of "a" as the first character.

So, I would like to know how to match the first part "xxx" in the email `"xxx@yyy.zzz"` in a way that it checks the entire string from first char till it reaches the @ symbol with the condition that it should take only a to z as valid value.

In other words, the regex should not mind the length of the username part of email, and irrespective of the number of chars entered, it should test it based on the specified regex condition, and it should test it for the set of chars from index 1 to index of @.

Comment: Why you think "a999@aaa.aaa" would evalute as true? `/[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/.test("a999@foo.com") === false` (you are missing a `+` for the part of the mail address after the @-sign)

Comment: I missed out the + sign while typing the question. Have edited the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression will not show `a999@aaa.aaa` to be a match. It will, however, show that `9999a@aaa.aaa9999` is a match. The regular expression markers you're missing are `^` for the start of string and `$` for end of string. This is what you're looking for:

```
/^[a-z]{1,}@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$/
```

You can test this expression out over on this online validator: http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/#

Comment: bang! i did work with the ^ actually, but never bothered to add the $ at the end of the expression. $ thing was a new stuff for me. Thanks, this expression worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
/[a-z]+@[a-z]\.[a-z]+/
```

will not match "aaa@aaa.aaa", but will match "aaa@a.aaa". You are only allowing for a **single** lowercase letter between the @ and the .

Again, the string "a999@aaa.aaa" will not match. [a-z]+ means look for one or more characters between a and z... digits are not included, so 999 wil not be matched.

does the regex

/[a-z]+@[a-z]+/.[a-z]+/

do what you want?

Comment: "/[a-z]+@[a-z]+/.[a-z]+/" was what I also meant, somehow while typing the question i missed out the "+" required after the @[a-z].
Now, my original question - how do I match an arbitrary length of string with a pattern? Since [a-z]+ will match "one"or more, so giving "a999"@ will also return true, since a has matched the pattern, correct? What I am looking for is some sort of pattern matching that looks into the whole length of the string from a till the last 9 in "a99999@xyz.com"...